# Laravel Route modal binding for category, subcategory and products on slug url

Tags: laravel, binding, model

I have three models:**Category, Subcategory And Product**, I want my URL to be something like this:
www.mydomain.com/electronics/mobile/samsung_galaxy
**(www.mydomain.com/category/sub-category/product)**

Comment: It's unclear what you want !

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be constructed like this to accept the needed parameters.

```php
Route::get("{category}/{subcategory}/{product}", ["uses" => "SomeController@method"]);
```

Then you can retrieve them in your controller.

```php
public function method($category, $subcategory, $product) {
    // Do magic with the variables.
}
```

If you would like to generate a url in your views, you should add an alias to your route:

```php
Route::get("{category}/{subcategory}/{product}", ["uses" => "SomeController@method", "as" => "product"]);
```

... then do this in your blade files

```php
{{ route("product", [$category, $subcategory, $product]) }}
```

The first parameter should contain the name/alias of your route. Next is an array of variables you would like to fill in your route parameters.